How to write/ export raster stack as NetCDF file without losing layer values
I currently have a raster stack of environmental data, where each layer is a daily mean value. Reading/ importing this into R and analysing it works fine. However, when I write/ export it as a NetCDF and try to load it into ArcGIS, the values/ range for each layer are 0. I've tried this with other datasets and it works fine.
This is the code I'm using:
raster::writeRaster(resampled_EKE, 
                    file = "D:/filepathway/EKE2.nc", 
                    format = "CDF",
                    overwrite = TRUE)


If you have "tried this with other datasets and it works fine" then you have likely identified the issue is with this specific object. As such, you will need to provide a minimal, reproducible example. This link has some really useful guidance regarding how to create an MRE, and how to share example data in particular.

Having said that, does the issue persist if you convert your data to a SpatRaster (if it isn't already, just assuming as you declared raster in your code)? And then use terra::writeRaster()?

@LTyrone thanks for the reply. I'm reading in the original .nc file using raster::stack, performing my analyses and then trying to export using the code above. When I read in the exported file back into R, it appears to be correct, however not in ArcGIS. So I wonder if the problem is there and not in R?? I thought initially it might be an exporting issue and should begin with that?

I think a full repex is required here in order to determine this issue (see my first comment). You could create a 'toy' dataset to dput() into your question that replicates the issue, or subset the extent of the actual data that you are using so that it is small enough to dput(). Just ensure the issue is reproduced on the data you supply. Good luck!
